# Embedded SQL server setup up with Visual Studio Express 2010 (or even 2008)?

Tags: c#, sql

Would anyone mind explaining (or pointing me to a tutorial) how to setup an SQL embedded server with Visual Studio Express edition?

I'm not concerned with getting the Designer tab working, but I'm trying to achieve a few basic things:

1. Access the database via file path
2. read/write to database file
3. password to connect to database (not too big of an issue)

The solution I've been pointed to was **SQLite** to do so, and have seen **ADO.Net** and **Entity Framework** to connect the file to the project. So I guess a few important aspects would be that once I set the database up with the project can I

1. send the projects back and forth to multiple developers?
2. who are on different computers *who have not installed any SQL
   related anything*?
3. And is SQLite a viable solution for this?

I've been trying to get a working solution for about 7 hours now.

Comment: i suggest you, use SqlCompact 4.0 instate of Sqlite. read more http://erikej.blogspot.com

Comment: Thank you so much! Will this solution be easily transferable between computers?

Comment: 1: Instal Nuget, 2:select the the EricEj SqlCe Membership package. Should work in less than 7 minutes.

Comment: Aren't Visual Studio extensions for professional only?

Comment: you can easily transfer database between machines. not sure for about addons limitation, but you can use stand alone version of SqlCompact 4.0 toolbox from here http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Wow up and running already! @Jalalx, could you move your comment to an answer so I can accept it? (and possibly link a tutorial on connecting to the compact DB -- theres a LOT of information of erikej's blogspot and I'm still looking for it)

Comment: You're part right. Nuget is only available in the WebDev express. A pity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you, use SqlCompact 4.0 instead of Sqlite.

You can download SqlCompact 4.0 from [Microsoft download center](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876). Also you can easily transfer database between machines. Read about [Private Deployment here](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html). And finally an awesome [toolbox for using SqlCompact 4.0](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) stand alone or addons for Visual Studio

Comment: my native language is not English, sorry for that :P

Comment: Thats fine! Thanks so much for the help!